# Win32 API failure

Tags: winapi

Is it necessary to check all `Win32 APIs` return values? For example, functions like `AdjustWindowRect`, `SetWindowLong`, `GetWindowLong` etc. can really fail (have an internal error) or the return value is mostly a fail-safe mechanism of not inputting wrong arguments?

Comment: Each API's failure mode and how you check is documented in MSDN. You should handle what you can and fail/raise any others. NEVER silently drop unexpected results.

Comment: @Deanna: but the failure conditions and categorizations are rarely documented in MSDN. It's not documented in which circumstances `SetWindowLong` will cause `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` (which should be "never").

Comment: @Tinctorius That comes under "unexpected results" and should be grounds to give up as something has gone wrong that you can't handle. You can howver handles errors you expect.

Comment: @Deanna: the documentation on MSDN doesn't give you a list of errors *to expect*. Therefore, it is incomplete. It's really not enough that you can guess which errors can be caused.

Comment: @Tinctorius: You're missing the point. You shouldn't handle everythign it can through. You should handle the few errors that you expect and can do something with (this file is read only, out of disk space, etc) MSDN tells you how it reports it's errors so just look for the ones you expect. Everything else should be fatal and unhandleable. There is no point in handle all several billion possible error code as at least several billion of them would be "something went wrong".

Comment: @Deanna: there is indeed no point in handling all several billion possible error codes, because only a handful are thrown by the mentioned APIs -- barring very exceptional cases. Those very exceptional cases, yes, you can leave them unhandled. But the handful of errors to be expected, **those** errors *must* be documented. They aren't, and thus, MSDN is a very poor documentation for the Win32 API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike POSIX, it seems that the Win32 API doesn't give a nice list of error conditions for every call. Although some functions can't fail in practice (except in the case of bad arguments), they *can* fail in theory. Just like you shouldn't trust user input, you also shouldn't blindly trust poorly documented libraries.

I think the best way to deal with the APIs is to wrap all calls in functions to do the error checking (which differ widely between and within the APIs), so that you have sort of a "higher level" API where all peculiarities are ironed out. You can then translate successes, errors, and warnings to whatever technique is suitable in your language (e.g. exceptions, error/warning callbacks, sum types).

Comment: I don't know what you mean. When a function returns an error (`0` in WIN32 parlance, usually), you call `GetLastError()` (instead of looking up `errno` on Linux) and compare it to the list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What I mean by the first sentence is that certain calls can only cause certain error codes. For instance, it makes no sense for `ReadFile` to cause `ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT` or `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS`. For every function individually, the set of possible errors is very small, but the exact set is rarely documented for the Win32 API. For POSIX, however, all error codes are listed and explained, not only because they have a more specific meaning in the context of the specific call, but also because, for instance, the `ENOENT` error makes no sense if it is returned by `fread` or `fgetc`.